# Is $(X + Y)^2 = X^2 + 2XY + Y^2$ for two random variables $X$ and $Y$?

Tags: probability, random-variables

If $X$ and $Y$ were real numbers or something then certainly $(X + Y)^2 = X^2 + 2XY + Y^2$. But can we say the same thing if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables? Those are very different things than numbers, so I didn't want to assume that we can perform arithmetic with them as if they were.

Comment: Try to recall the definitions of $X+Y$ and $X^2$ (or $XY$) for random variables $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Random variables are functions. So, if $X$ and $Y$ map into the reals, then yes, this holds.

Answer (score 4):

Random variables are just functions $\Omega \to \mathbb R$. For any real-valued functions $f$ and $g$, we have 
$$(f+g)^2=f^2+2fg+g^2,$$
so yes, this holds.

Comment: Why do you repeat my comment?

Comment: @amsmath I just read it, sorry. Why comment if what you're saying is an answer?

Comment: I think it was appropriate as a comment. It was not written formally like your answer is.